# Bizarre Join with comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking at someone else's code and find this bizarre join:

```sql
SELECT 
SUM(
    (
      intUnitOverheadCost + intUnitLaborCost + intUnitMaterialCost + intUnitSubcontractCost 
      + intUnitDutyCost + intUnitFreightCost + intUnitMiscCost
    ) 
    * 
    (
            (
                CASE 
                    WHEN imtSource = 3
                        THEN - 1
                    ELSE 1
                END
            ) * intQuantity
    )
)
FROM PartTransactions               --imt
INNER JOIN PartTransactionCosts     --int
    ON imtPartTransactionID = intPartTransactionID
LEFT JOIN Warehouses                --imw
    ON imtPartWarehouseLocationID = imwWarehouseID
        , ProductionProperties      --xap <-- weird join
WHERE imtJobID = jmpJobID
AND imtSource IN (2,3)
AND imtReceiptID = ''
AND Upper(imtTableName) <> 'RECEIPTLINES'
AND imtNonInventoryTransaction <= {?CHECKBOXGROUP_4_ShowNonInventory}
AND imtJobType IN (1, 3)
AND imtTransactionDate < DATEADD(d, 1, {?PROMPT_1_TODATE})
AND (
    imtNonNettable = 0
    OR (
        imtNonNettable <> 0
        AND ISNULL(imwDoNotIncludeInJobCosts, 0) = 0
        )
    )
AND intCostType = (
    CASE -- Always 1
        WHEN xapIMCostingMethod = 1
            THEN 1
        WHEN xapIMCostingMethod = 2
            THEN 2
        WHEN xapIMCostingMethod = 3
            THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END
)
```

There is only one record in table ProductionProperties and the result of `select xapIMCostingMethod  from ProductionProperties` is always 1.

There are always 4 enumerated results in PartTransactionCosts, but only 1 result is allowed.

ProductionProperties.xapIMCostingMethod is implicitly joining to PartTransactionCosts.intCostType

My specific question is what is really going on with this comma join? It looks like it has to be a cross-join, later filtered in the WHERE clause with one possible result.

Comment: those are implicit joins, and it's just as you think, a `CROSS JOIN` where the "join conditions" are in the `WHERE`

Comment: The explicit equivalent would be `CROSS JOIN ProductionProperties` instead which would be far better as mixing ANSI-89 and ANSI-92 syntax is really confusing.

Comment: If any of the columns from `ProductionProperties` *are* mentioned in the `WHERE` (we can't tell as not one of the columns are qualified, which is a terrible idea) with an expression against a column from another table, then you would be far better off converting the `CROSS JOIN` to a proper `INNER JOIN`, and moving the clauses to the `ON`.

Comment: Thank you lamak and lamu. I do spend a good deal of my time refactoring and explicitizing code I inherit from the vendor (ECI, for M1 ERP). I would upvote your comment if it were possible (I upvoted steve's below, for providing triple consensus). Anyway, I have no clout, so my upvotes don't count.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer. It is a cartesian join but since the rows are 1 it doesn't cause an issue.

I'm thinking if you added rows to ProductionProperties then it would serve as a multiplier for your sum. I did a little experiment to show the issue:

```
declare @tableMoney table (
unit int,
Product char(5),
xapIMPCostingMethod int,
Cost money
)
declare @tableProdProperties table (
xapIMPCostingMethod int
)

insert @tableMoney (unit, Product, xapIMPCostingMethod, Cost)
values
(1,'bike',1, 2.00),
(1,'car',1, 2.25),
(2,'boat',2, 4.50)

insert @tableProdProperties (xapIMPCostingMethod)
values (1),
(2)


select sum(Cost)
from @tableMoney, @tableProdProperties
```

I also don't like to use joins where it isn't clear what is joining to what so I always use an alias:

```
select sum(Cost)
from @tableMoney tbm join @tableProdProperties tpp
on tbm.xapIMPCostingMethod = tpp.xapIMPCostingMethod
```